# Where clause retrieve data after passing unknown string value . Why?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = "60dsfdsf"
```

In phpmyadmin, if run this query, then it will retrieve `column_name` value 60 form `table_name` .

Here `column_name` type is int and primary .

I was expecting not to find any value but it's retrieving `column_name` value 60

what's the reason behind that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is MySQL which is casting the value as per it type. If the column has a type as INT and passed value contains the string having a number, it will extract number out of it.

As per the [type-conversion-MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa.

So in your case,

`SELECT * FROM`table_name`WHERE`column_name`= "60dsfdsf"`

is actually converting to

`SELECT * FROM`table_name`WHERE`column_name`= "60"`

EDIT:

if your string is starting with the number then the MySql will take that number.

eg. `60dsfdsf` is `60`

BUT, if the string has alphabets initially then the result will be

eg. `dsfdsf60` is `0` for MySQL.

So be careful since it will not be the same result for each case. The better way, before passing value convert or extract the number and then send it to query.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken it automatically cast data into the required type. In this case it will disregards the last characters and go with the numbers from the beginning of the string

If you start with an alphabetical character you will see it won't load any value.